# Why does read not work yet fgets work fine in my program?

Tags: c, cygwin, system-calls, fgets

So the specific part of my program looks like this:

```
printf("Please input command:\n>");
While 1 {
    if ((int c = read(STDIN_FILENO, input, Buffer_size) == 0) {
        break;
    }
    rest of the program uses strtok to break the input 
    down and store in array. Then pass it to a function which checks for 
    various commands and prints whatever was the command 
    suppose to do or gives syntax error for incorrect commands

    printf(">"); //last line

}
```

So here's what happens:

```
Please input command:
addperson Batman
>person added
blahblah
Error: incorrect syntax
```

For some reason it doesn't print: ">". Also everytime I enter anything after that it says the same thing always even with right commands.

But if I use this:

```
printf("Please input command:\n>");
while 1 {
    if (fgets(input, Buffer_size, stdin) == NULL) {
        break;
    }
    ...
    printf(">");

}
```

I get:

```
Please input command:
> add_person Batman
person added
> blahbagwa
Incorrect syntax
> add_person Superman
person added
```

Notice how ">" appears in each output? I don't really know why read isn't working properly; perhaps my understand of read isn't very good. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`read()` will block until it has received enough input to fill the entire buffer where as `fgets()` will return a buffer for each entered line.

Comment: Do you mean that if it doesn't fill the buffer it won't continue running the next line?

Comment: @shn you will get the next line in the same buffer, ie it will contain all input (even truncated) up to when then buffer is full. `read()` will like wait (block) until the buffer is full.

Comment: Is it actually possible to avoid that problem? I tried doing bzero(input, Buffer_size) before the read line. Still doesn't work properly as giving the wrong syntax causes printing issues.

Comment: @shn output mismatch can also happen due to out of synched file flushing, ie when not ending a `printf()` with "\n". Try doing `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf()`'s

Comment: @shn ...also note that the command parsing can easily come out of synch if you use `read()` (you can get several lines of command in each buffer) if you do not handle that case.

Comment: This is wrong.  `read()` will not block until the buffer is full.

Comment: That did the trick. I used fflush as flush was giving compile error. For a second I was ready to curse at C for being so annoying. I still don't get why this printf("Please input command:\n>"); wouldn't print the >, but I guess as you said it has to do synched file flushing.

Comment: If you use stdin and stdout, they synchronize with each other.  If you use stdout and the file descriptor, you don't get that luxury, and you have to flush output.  There is line buffering (what you're seeing), full buffering, and no buffering.  Only in extremis do you use no buffering on a standard I/O channel.